# working with little data

Tags: regression

I am not a stats major but only an applied math major and I need help with a project I am doing. Basically, we've data for 40 weeks or so and for each week there are a number of cases. I have data from 2002 - 2013 however as we go down the years, we have less data (0 data in some years also)

For 2002, I have enough data to plot this:
[image]
 which I assume is some sort of gamma distribution.

however, for 2003, it looks something like this:

```
week cnt
7    4
35   2
36   3
37   2
38   2
40   1
```

so the picture looks like:
[image: http://imgur.com/Nq5b7AL]

What can I do with this data? To be clear, I am not trying to see a pattern between the years. I'll be trying to see a pattern between some other factors and this data.

Can I add 0s in for the missing weeks? Should I combine 4 weeks into one month and have months on the x-axis (still dosn't get rid of the missing data).  For some years I only have 4 data points.

Comment: "*which I assume is some sort of gamma distribution.*"  - you're observing data values over time, and those aren't displayed as a density. On what basis do you say "gamma distribution"?

Comment: @Glen_b I guess by the shape of it. From your comment, I assume thats not enough. What can I do?

Comment: Whether you should add 0s depends on whether assessments were taken at those time points. If they were & nothing was found, then 0s belong. Otherwise, you just have data at irregular intervals. Other notes: these data won't be gamma, but [Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) or some over-dispersed relative of Poisson (eg, [negative binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)); you should presumably be using time-series methods as the data will not be independent.

Comment: masfenix but density is the shape of $f_Y(y)$ vs $y$, not some vague sense of curvature in a plot of $y$ vs $t$.

Comment: @gung NB sounds like what I need. Any introductory stuff on time-series methods?

Comment: I'm not an expert on t-s methods. Try searching the site. I suspect some of what you need has already been discussed.

Comment: If you have so few data points, why not just display them as a time series plot and/or as a histogram (frequency distribution of cases).  I don't think summary statistics will add anything that you can't see plainly.